# Xamarin MVVM Forms Trigger Event in a Content View

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

having trouble triggering an event on a video control in a content view.
I have a Page Content with a Content view (video player), now this video player has a method "start", how to invoke this method on View Model or View Model Base?

I have tried vlc and it works because there is a property libvlc I can bind the entire control to the view model, but this specific player there is no property to bind, its not opensource its a webrtc player for xamarin.

I tried

<video:Player BindingContext="{Binding VarInViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}" />  but when i call the method in my viewbase or viewmodel the player doesnt seem to play, although it works in codebehind of the content view if I specific call the play referencing the name.

this player is not opensource, there are also methods like "on error event", how to bind this method on my viewmodel? so I can change properties on my content view

thank you

Comment: First get it to work WITHOUT any binding. Add that "hardcoded" working code to your question. Then it might be possible for someone to help you figure out how to bind.

Comment: please post the relevant code, properly formatted, instead of one line of unformatted XAML